# can hg copy be used with hg merge?

Tags: mercurial

From one source file I made a copy using hg copy.

Now I'm going to Change some stuff in the second file (the copy) and I want to be able to merge the future changes of the original file into the second file.

Can this be done using hg merge? Right now when I try to do something like

```
hg merge NewFile.html -r 130:f24199b5b945
```

using the most current changeset of the original file, I get an error: abort: please specify just one revision.

Comment: Can you use some kind of templating or include system to include the common bits between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the two files are separate after that, and except for one file originating from the other, they do not share any history after that.

You will either have to duplicate your modifications in the other file, or you need to find another way to do this.